# I'm changing LSB values of pixel in my image, but it's not taking effect (Java)

Tags: java, rgb

I've researched thoroughly through every questions, but alas! So, here's my problem, what I'm trying to do is change the LSB of RGB values in an image. I've used getRGB() to get the RGB values at a particular pixel, converted the individual R, G and B values to 8 bit and I'm trying to replace their LSB by a bit from another source (a text for eg). An illustration:
@ pixel (0, 1) R=0111010, G=0011101 and B=1101001 and I wanna replace their LSB by 101, that is new values will be R=011101(1), G=001110(0) and B=110100(1). The thing is after I processed it and saved my image, it doesn't really save it. Here is my code

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter URL: ");
    String imageURL = input.next();

    File file = new File(imageURL);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

    String flag = "011111000111110011";
    int pixelX = 0;
    int pixelY = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<flag.length(); i+=3){
        int pixel = image.getRGB(pixelX, pixelY);
        int  red   = (pixel & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
        int  green = (pixel & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
        int  blue  =  pixel & 0x000000ff;
        System.out.println("\n@ pixel: "+pixelX+pixelY+"\nred: "+red+"green: "+green+"blue: "+blue);

        String binRed = roundTo8(Integer.toBinaryString(red));
        String binGreen = roundTo8(Integer.toBinaryString(green));
        String binBlue = roundTo8(Integer.toBinaryString(blue));
        System.out.println("\nbinRed: "+binRed+"\nbinGreen: "+binGreen+"\nbinBlue: "+binBlue);

        String flagRed = flag.substring(i, (i+1));
        String flagGreen = flag.substring((i+1), (i+2));
        String flagBlue = flag.substring((i+2), (i+3));
        System.out.println("\nflagRed: "+flagRed+"\nflagGreen: "+flagGreen+"\nflagBlue: "+flagBlue);

        if(!(flagRed.equals(binRed.charAt(7)))){
            binRed = (binRed.substring(0, 7)).concat(flagRed);
            System.out.print("\nnew binRed: "+binRed);
        }

        if(!(flagGreen.equals(binGreen.charAt(7)))){
            binGreen = (binGreen.substring(0, 7)).concat(flagGreen);
            System.out.print("\nnew binGreen: "+binGreen);
        }

        if(!(flagBlue.equals(binBlue.charAt(7)))){
            binBlue = (binBlue.substring(0, 7)).concat(flagBlue);
            System.out.print("\nnew binBlue: "+binBlue);
        }

        System.out.print("\nnew red: "+Integer.parseInt(binRed, 2));
        System.out.print("\nnew green: "+Integer.parseInt(binGreen, 2));
        System.out.print("\nnew blue: "+Integer.parseInt(binBlue, 2));
        System.out.println("==========");
        //

        int newRed = Integer.parseInt(binRed, 2);
        int newGreen = Integer.parseInt(binGreen, 2);
        int newBlue = Integer.parseInt(binBlue, 2);

        Color clr = new Color(newRed, newGreen, newBlue);
        int temp = clr.getRGB();
        image.setRGB(pixelX, pixelY, temp);

        try {
            File outputfile = new File("saved.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occured while saving the steg file.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        pixelX++;
    }
```

and i have used this code to test the code above:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter URL: ");
    String imageURL = input.next();

    File file = new File(imageURL);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

        for(int j=0; j<45; j++){
            int pixel = image.getRGB(j, 0);
            int  red   = (pixel & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            int  green = (pixel & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            int  blue  =  pixel & 0x000000ff;

            String binRed = roundTo8(Integer.toBinaryString(red));
            String binGreen = roundTo8(Integer.toBinaryString(green));
            String binBlue = roundTo8(Integer.toBinaryString(blue));

            System.out.print(binRed.charAt(7)+""+binGreen.charAt(7)+binBlue.charAt(7)+" ");
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you're saving your file in JPEG format.  JPEG is generally a lossy compression format (there is a variant of JPEG that is lossless but it is not commonly used), which means that it doesn't preserve the original pixel values exactly.  Try another format that is lossless, like png or bmp.